# PHP Division with variables, not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having some difficulties dividing a cart total on an e-commerce site, in order to create a deposit amount for a customer to pay.

As you'll see below, I am trying to display 25% of the order total as a deposit amount.  however, I have tried many variations of this, and all return "0".

If I echo any of the variable independently, they echo the correct value, but when dividing one by the other the result is "0" everytime.

Any help is appreciated, I feel like I am missing something very simple..

Thanks

```
<?php $amount = $woocommerce->cart->get_total(); ?>
                            <?php $percent = 4; ?>
                            <?php $deposit = $amount / $percent; ?>


                            <strong><?php echo $deposit; ?></strong>
```

Comment: What does `echo $amount;` output?

Comment: the cart total.. in this particular case, $1200 or so.

Comment: Do you mean `var_dump($amount);`?

it is this:  `string(41) "
$1,022.29
"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use casts -> **(field_type)**:

```
<?php $amount = $woocommerce->cart->get_total(); ?>
                            <?php $percent = 4; ?>
                            <?php $deposit = (float)$amount / (int)$percent; ?>


                            <strong><?php echo $deposit; ?></strong>
```

With cast you can convert from one type to other.

For example if with **$woocommerce->cart->get_total();** you get **string**, with ***(float)*** you convert to **float**

> [PHP.NET about casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 0):

`$commerce->cart->get_total();` function responds output such as `<span class="amount">560&nbsp;&euro;</span>` ($1,022.29) and you need to convert this to a number so you can get a fee (25 %) from the amount.

First of all, the problem here is that the get_total() function responds with a string.

The correct way to fix this string would be a simple example such as

```
<?php
    $totalAmountString = $commerce->cart->get_total(); //<span class="amount">560&nbsp;&euro;</span>
    $totalAmountString = strip_tags($totalAmountString); //get rid of the span - we're left with "560&nbsp;&euro;"
    $totalAmountString = str_replace(array("&nbsp;&#38;", ","), "", $totalAmountString);
    $totalAmountFloat = (float)$totalAmountString;
    $percentage = 0.25;
    $deposit = $totalAmountFloat * $percentage;

    var_dump($deposit);
?>
```

We are removing all the html. When you var_dump had a string length of 41 i knew that's where the problem is. It is returning the span tags and html within the string. You only see the number because the html is hidden. This line `$totalAmountString = str_replace(array("&nbsp;&#38;", ","), "", $totalAmountString);` may need editing depending on the currency symbol used, `&#38` is a dollar, but it could be done two or three different ways. Hope this helps.

Comment: `<?php $amount = $woocommerce->cart->get_total(); ?>
                            <?php $percent = 0.25; ?>
                            <?php $deposit = $amount * $percent; ?>
                            <strong><?php echo $deposit; ?></strong>`

\

This returns 0 as well.. It should be returning 25% of the get_total value.. I can't figure this out.

Comment: If this is returning 0 then your `$amount` is not an `int` or ` `float`. For testing purposes please `var_dump($amount);` and let me know what it says. I'll then be able to code/advise on the way forward.

Comment: it is this: `string(41) "
$1,022.29
"`

Thanks for tthe help, I appreciate it

Comment: ok, so if it has spaces around it as in your example then do this `<?php $amount = (float)trim($amount); ?>` otherwise do this `<?php $amount = (float) $amount; ?>`

Comment: `<?php $amount = $woocommerce->cart->get_total(); ?>
                            <?php $amount = (float)trim($amount);  ?>
                            <?php $percent = 0.25; ?>
                            <?php $deposit = $amount * $percent; ?>
                            <?php echo $amount.' '.$deposit ?>
                            <?php var_dump($amount); ?>`


I am getting a 0 for $amount when the float and trim are used.  Here is the total results seen on the page: `0 0 float(0)`   Any idea @Vector?

Comment: The comma is screwing it up. We need to run string replace to remove it. I'll edit my code

Comment: that hasn't changed anything.. 0 for all values.  Do we need to change the string to an (int)? before we can multiply it by 0.25?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Dylan: can you test if my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18552281/1438393) solves your issue?

Comment: If you `var_dump($amount);` at the end, is it a float with the comma removed?

Comment: @Dylan, why is this a comment on my answer?

Comment: @ Amal Murali, I tested and commented on you answer, thanks.  I am keeping an eye on it.  I'll comment with you there.

Comment: @Vector, I am getting a `float(0)` returned.  I am not sure why it isn't working.. It seems like it should be a simple fix.  Thanks for all you effort.  Any more ideas?

Comment: I'm sure between you, me and @Amal we'll get there. One this that is confusing is that when you `var_dump($amount);` at the start, it shows as a string with 41 chars, there's something not right there and i think that's ultimately where the root of the problem is

Comment: @Vector, true. The string is much short than that, it would seem.  Hopefully, we can get this.

Comment: have you tried this `$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total()` in your code instead of `$woocommerce->cart->get_total()`

Comment: @Vector, that uses the price before taxes and shipping, and returns `float(0)` in the end.

Comment: I figured out why your string is so long. See my edit. It is because the string is in fact returning a bunch of html too. That is why it will never ever convert. I've posted a fix.

Comment: @Vector, i think this is close, it is still returning 0, but I can see the string is much shorter.  It all looks good until the float is introduced, and the multiplier returns 0.  Do you think we need to remove the $ sign from the string, and turn it in to an integer number before performing the multiply?

Comment: We need to remove `$` and anything else that isn't just the number

Answer (score 0):

if the output of amount has a currency sign, you can strip the currency sign off by getting the float value using floatval

```
<?php $amount = $woocommerce->cart->get_total(); ?>
                            <?php $percent = 4; ?>
                            <?php $deposit = floatval($amount) / $percent; ?>


                            <strong><?php echo $deposit; ?></strong>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I am still getting a "0" returned.  The value does contain a $ before the number, but when i `echo (float)$amount;`  I get a "0".  when i `echo $amount` I get the value.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `$amount` is in the form " $1,022.29 " try this:

```
<?php $amount = $woocommerce->cart->get_total(); ?>
                            <?php $percent = 4; ?>
                            <?php $deposit = preg_replace('/^( \$)?([0-9.]+) ?$/', '$2', str_replace(',', '', $amount)) / $percent; ?>


                            <strong><?php echo $deposit; ?></strong>
```

Comment: thanks.  This returns "0".  However, it is an `int` so that is a good sign.

Comment: What happens if you run this? `var_dump(preg_replace('/^( \$)?([0-9.]+) ?$/', '$2', str_replace(',', '', $amount)));`